# How would one replace Processing IDE with Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Tags: visual-studio, processing

I have been unable to find any information how would one replace [Processing](http://processing.org) IDE with Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Is it even possible to replace it, if yes then how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Processing. Can you provide some examples on how you use it (for programming with OpenGL maybe)? Not sure if it possible to simply switch from processing to Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing is a couple of things:

- A set of tools that convert "Processing code" into Java code, or JavaScript code with Processing.js.
- An IDE that lets you write Processing code and use those tools.
- A Java library (and JavaScript, for Processing.js) that is called by that converted code.

That third thing is what you care about. You can use Processing as a Java library the same way you can use any Java library. [Here](https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/) is a tutorial on using it from eclipse.

The steps to use it with Visual Studio will be similar: find the Processing library jar (probably called **core.jar**), add it to your classpath, and then write Java code that uses the classes from that library jar.

However, I will say that you should know what you're doing with both Java and Processing before trying this. Processing's IDE is designed to make things as simple as possible, so it hides a lot of behind-the-scenes stuff from you. You have to be comfortable with the idea of using an API, OOP, and setting up the classpath.

Also note that Processing 3 has changed a bunch of things, so certain aspects of that tutorial are out of date. Most notably, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet`, so you can't treat it as a component anymore. You have to go through its `Surface` instead. If you have no idea what I'm talking about, it might be a better idea to stick with Processing's included IDE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I asked was because I started using Visual Micro plugin for VS2015 and I really like it, but the PC half of my project is written in Processing and I would have wanted to edit and debug it in VS too.